# An unexpected result of comparing strings in Sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to retrieve result set which conditions the value of 'uid' is bigger than '10000', and they are all vchar() type;

Result's like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It looks like you are making it a string which you can't compare an int to a string.** In Python I ran:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE rowid > 9
```

And it worked fine try changing it from a literal (the " ' ") to an int.

To set your varchar(s) to int you can cast it so you don't change your table at all, using:

```
CAST(uid AS INT)
```

you can also (as @laalto mentioned) compare two strings with the >/< sign, so for that just I believe you can cast the number as a string (but I do believe it most be done with the CAST statement, not just the quotes) Note I could be wrong about this though as I have never used either I just cast the ID as an INT.

If you are interested in the CAST command, you can read more [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/07/sql-server-convert-text-to-numbers-integer-cast-and-convert/).
and of course the official documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

**Here's a copy and paste version for you as well:**

```
SELECT * FROM 'IMMessageInfo' WHERE CAST(uid as INT) > 10000 ORDER BY uid DESC
```

(full code is as follows (It is python 2.7.6; so it may look a little different from what you are using :) )

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab (rowid int, data text)''')

c.execute("INSERT INTO tab (rowid, data) VALUES (10, 'MynameisMike')")
conn.commit()

c.execute("SELECT * FROM tab WHERE rowid > 9")
print(c.fetchone())
```

Comment: For what it's worth, you *can* compare strings but the ordering is lexicographic . `'9005' > '10000'` since `'9' > '1'`.

Comment: Actually, that is a very good point I forgot about, I'll be adding that to my answer.

Comment: @laalto That's my confusion. I can't understand why '9005' > '10000' at here, the result set also shows that point. You mean strings comparing in Sqlite is restrict lexicographic, but how does it work?

Comment: Did you try it with the CAST statement?

Comment: @StevenByrne Yes. 'CAST(uid AS INT)' makes my world calm down and the problem solved, but I still want to know what's the lexicographic order?

Comment: @StevenByrne Can u explain it to me? Here's a huge of thanks !

Comment: To be completely honest with you, I have no idea why, from what I understand (which is fairly limited) It's just how SQL demands it to be done. Maybe @laalto could give us both some insight?

Comment: @laalto StevenByrne and I are waiting for you...and your brilliant answer.

Comment: By the way, @JerryRay if this answered your posted question I would appreciate it if you accepted the answer :)

Comment: @StevenByrne All right. No problem! But let's waiting for the answer firstly.

Comment: Hi @laalto , where are you? We need you !

Comment: Everything I wanted to add was already in the first comment. String comparison works left to right, one character at a time.

Comment: @laalto OK, got it. Lexicographic order means two strings comparison is no matter with length of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast it as INT, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM IMMessageInfo 
WHERE CAST(uid AS INT) > 10000
ORDER BY CAST(uid AS INT) DESC
```